# IntelliJ Plugin: Add entry to Git log branches context menu

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

I want to create a plugin that adds an entry to the context menu when the user performs a right click on the branches in git log. What is the corresponding group id?

[image]

Currently I only have the item in the context menu of the commits:

```xml
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
</extensions>

<actions>
   <action id="GitlabMergeRequestAction"
           class="com.mypackage.myplugin.action.MyAction"
           text="Custom context menu entry">
           <add-to-group group-id="Git.Log.ContextMenu" anchor="first"/>
   </action>
</actions>
```

Comment: I'd recommend you raise this issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development to discuss it with the IDEA team directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the question in the intellij community. Unfortunately the context menu is not extensible, because it is created programatically.
See
https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/git4idea/src/git4idea/ui/branch/GitBranchPopupActions.java.